# Should I return an array instead of individual values?

Tags: c#, json, rest

We have a C# WebAPI that interacts with a ReactJS frontend, using REST and JSON. We stumbled upon a situation where we need to send a considerable amount of data from the server to the client.

The format is basically:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        description: "description for Id 1",
        parentId: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        description: "description for Id 2",
        parentId: 1
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        description: "description for Id 3",
        parentId: 2
    },
   ......
]
```

Our frontend dev is trying to convince me to use an array like this instead:

```
[
    [1, 'description for Id 1', 1],
    [2, 'description for Id 2', 1],
    [3, 'description for Id 3', 2],
    ....
]
```

This of course makes the JSON a bit more lightweight, but I argue that this is a unnecessary hack that destroys the logic and descriptiveness of the format.

My question is:

Is it a bad practice? Does this break the "expected" contract between server and client? Or is it a normal optimization practice?

P.S.: Before writing this question, I was in doubt if this would be closed as a "primary opinion based question", but I do not believe this to be the case.

Comment: Part of this question will have answers based on opinions, which is not all that constructive here on Stack Overflow. To answer one of your questions, will it break the contract? Well, the two json formats define completely different structures, a client able to handle the first format will not automatically be able to handle the second, and vice versa.

Comment: I think you are right on two accounts - the question will be closed for being opinion based, and the flattened array loses context of the meaning of the data.

Comment: As for "normal optimization practice", the first step on "normal optimization practice" is to first verify that you *need* to optimize something, and then to measure what you have to figure out *what* you need to optimize. I would never change the structure from objects with properties to a flattened unstructured array without solid evidence that this improves *something*. If all you have is the opinion of your frontend developer, then to me that would not cut it.

Comment: We've run into these types of optimization problems in the past. The initial way we handled it was to return paginated responses and allow the frontend to dictate certain paging paging behaviors (ie: Posts Per Page, and page number) through query parameters. Another option we provided was to allow field filtering to offer the frontend to dictate only the required fields they needed for that particular request. But I agree with the above sentiments, you'll probably get a lot of opinions on this.

Comment: Ok guys, thank you for the insights. I will delete this question in a few seconds as it is opinion based.

Comment: I don't think this is opinion based. Indeed, The answer of @Blindy is very interesting for all of us.

Comment: @Alpha75 So you feel there is an objectively correct answer to this question?  Saying that someone posted an opinion that you found interesting doesn't mean the question isn't opinion based.

Comment: If there can be an objective answer it means that the question can be a good one. If the size saving in the answers is no longer a problem, the question is no longer opinion based. And this answer is available to everyone to know that detail that at least seems interesting to me.

Comment: @Alpha75 Yes, I wrote the "P.S." in the question with that in mind. I believe that there can be a very objective and unbiased answer. Anyway, we already have two votes to close  =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that data is sent gzipped unless you really messed up your server settings. Comparing those two (small) samples' gzipped form, the difference is ~20 bytes (101 bytes vs 77 bytes).

And it will only get smaller, relatively speaking, the more entries you have, because the common parts remain unchanged, they only need to be encoded once.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. In fact, we are gzipping the response. In my tests with 30k objects, the difference is negligible, and does not pay off the mess with the format.

Comment: Precisely why JSON is so widely used, the key names are reused so often that gzip makes them essentially free!